TypeError: Cannot read properties of null
I'm having problem on my components called RecipeItemPage for rendering content of food recipes that I fetch from forkify API.
I'm passing the return data from useFetch hook as a props to RecipeItemPage on the RecipeItem components that are used to retrieve routes from certain recipe by routing based on recipe_id
RecipeItem
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import useFetch from "../../hooks/useFetch";
import { Oval } from "react-loader-spinner";
import RecipeItemPage from "./RecipeItemPage";

function RecipeItem() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  console.log(id);
  const { data, error, loading: isLoading } = useFetch(id);
  console.log(data);

  return (
    <div className="home container mx-auto py-8 flex flex-wrap gap-10 justify-center">
      {isLoading && <Oval />}
      {!isLoading && !error && <RecipeItemPage data={data} />}
    </div>
  );
}

export default RecipeItem;

RecipeItemPage
function RecipeItemPage({ data }) {
  console.log(data);
  return (
    <div className="recipe-item-section container mx-auto px-5 py-8 grid grid-cols-1 lg:grid-cols-2 gap-8 lg:px-0">
      <div className="recipe-img-sec flex flex-col gap-5">
        <div className="img overflow-hidden rounded-xl border shadow-md lg:h-96 group"></div>
        <img
          className="w-full h-full object-cover group-hover:scale-105 duration-300"
          src={data.recipe.image_url}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default RecipeItemPage;

useFetch Hook

export default function useFetch(url) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async function () {
      try {
        setLoading(true);
        const response = await fetch(
          `https://forkify-api.herokuapp.com/api/get?rId=${url}`
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        setData(data);
      } catch (err) {
        setError(err);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    })();
  }, [url]);

  return { data, error, loading };
}

I get the error whenever I was routed to the RecipeItem although I already write the conditional rendering if !isLoading and !error then render the RecipeItemPage, but it keeps giving me error: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'recipe')".
Tried to pass conditional rendering to prevent the components render before its data done fetching.
I expect that the data is only rendered while its required the conditional rendering, but it gives me error that seems to be reading the data that hasn't received yet from the fetching hooks.

"but it gives me error that seems to be reading the data that hasn't received yet from the fetching Hooks" - Yes, that's likely the exact problem, data is empty/undefined/null/etc prior to data being fetched. Can you [edit] to share the useFetch hook implementation and any other code you feel might be relevant in a complete [mcve]?

I think data?.recipe?.image_url should work in that case.

@Pluto Yes, but wouldn't you consider that to be a bit of a "band-aid" fix/hack? We should attempt to investigate why data is unexpectedly still null first, right?

@DrewReese Thankyou for the MRE guide , i get more guide on how to make better quiestion here , By the way i somehow resolve the error that occur by changing the default value of isLoading state to true

First check if the data has the property recipe or not in your RecipeItemPage component. If it is, then return the component or return null.
function RecipeItemPage({ data }) {
  if(!data?.recipe) return null;

  console.log(data);
  return (
    <div className="recipe-item-section container mx-auto px-5 py-8 grid grid-cols-1 lg:grid-cols-2 gap-8 lg:px-0">
      <div className="recipe-img-sec flex flex-col gap-5">
        <div className="img overflow-hidden rounded-xl border shadow-md lg:h-96 group"></div>
        <img
          className="w-full h-full object-cover group-hover:scale-105 duration-300"
          src={data.recipe.image_url}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

OR
Simply replace the src={data.recipe.image_url} with src={data?.recipe?.image_url} in your RecipeItemPage component.

It would be better to add the conditional check in the parent component and keep this one dumb and not even render it until everything is present: !isLoading && !error && data && data.recipe && <RecipeItemPage data={data} />
